# how to collect information of this json file through django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

so, I'm creating a django weather app project. My idea is:

1. The user input the name of a city
2. The city need to be in my database
3. If it is, so the weather api will receive the city coordinates and output data

I would like to know how do I get parameters of a json file through django. Do I need to do it with the views? create a model? some request?

**views.py**:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import requests
from datetime import datetime 
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

def weatherdata(request):
    response = requests.get('api is here').json()
    context = {'response':response}
    return render(request,'home.html',context)

def citynamesinfo(request):
    
    response = request.FILES()
    #I don't what to do here


# input localization
# recognize specific coordenates
```

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Weather(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    temperature = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
    condition = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    precipitation = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    humidity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
```

considering the json file is like this:

```
[{"geoname_id": "3112344", "name": "R\u00e1fales", "ascii_name": "Rafales", "alternate_names": ["Rafales", "Rafels", "R\u00e1fales", "R\u00e1fels"], "feature_class": "P", "feature_code": "PPLA3", "country_code": "ES", "cou_name_en": "Spain", "country_code_2": null, "admin1_code": "52", "admin2_code": "TE", "admin3_code": "44194", "admin4_code": null, "population": 175, "elevation": null, "dem": 634, "timezone": "Europe/Madrid", "modification_date": "2012-03-04", "label_en": "Spain", "coordinates": {"lon": 0.01923, "lat": 40.8377}},
```

I'm about 2 hours looking to the code and searching in the web how do I do it but I'm not bearing it.

Comment: When user search 1) get data 2) save to db 3) show on home, when someone search same data use db to get data > show on home. If need further support, contact me.